# R baseline package saving plots in a loop

Tags: r, baseline

I'm trying to optimize the parameters for `baseline` in the R baseline package by changing each parameters in a loop and comparing plots to determine which parameters give me the best baseline.
I currently have the code written so that the loop produces each plot, but I'm having trouble with getting the plot saved as the class of each object I'm creating is a baseline package-specific (which I'm suspecting is the problem here).

```
foo <- data.frame(Date=seq.Date(as.Date("1957-01-01"), by = "day", 
                        length.out = ncol(milk$spectra)),
          Visits=milk$spectra[1,],
          Old_baseline_visits=milk$spectra[1,], row.names = NULL)
foo.t <- t(foo$Visits)
#the lines above were copied from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37346967/r-packagebaseline-application-to-sample-dataset to make a reproducible dataset

df <- expand.grid(lambda=seq(1,10,1), p=seq(0.01,0.1,0.01))
baselinediff <- list()

for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  thislambda <- df[i,]$lambda
  thisp <- df[i,]$p
  thisplot <- baseline(foo.t, lambda=thislambda, p=thisp, maxit=20, method='als')
  print(paste0("lambda = ", thislambda))
  print(paste0("p = ", thisp))
  print(paste0("index = ", i))
  baselinediff[[i]] <- plot(thisplot)
  jpeg(file = paste(baselinediff[[i]], '.jpeg', sep = ''))
  dev.off()
}
```

I know that I would be able to extract corrected spectra using `baseline.als` but I just want to save the plot images with the red baseline so that I can see how well the baselines are getting drawn. Any `baseline` users out there that can help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you change your loop in the following way:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  thislambda <- df[i,]$lambda
  thisp <- df[i,]$p
  thisplot <- baseline(foo.t, lambda=thislambda, p=thisp, maxit=20, method='als')
  print(paste0("lambda = ", thislambda))
  print(paste0("p = ", thisp))
  print(paste0("index = ", i))
  baselinediff[[i]] <- thisplot
  jpeg(file = paste('baseline', i, '.jpeg', sep = ''))
  plot(baselinediff[[i]])
  dev.off()
}
```

Note that this does not try to capture the already plotted element (`thisplot`) inside of the list. Instead, the plotting is done after you call the `jpeg` command. This solves your export issue. Another problem was the naming of the file. If you call  `baselinediff[[i]]` inside of `paste`, you apparently end up with an error. So I switched it to a simpler name. To plot your resulting list, call:

```
lapply(baselinediff, plot)
```

If you are determined on storing the *already* plotted element, the `capture.plot`function from the `imager` package might be a good start.

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to do, thank you so much!