# How to convert dataframe (or vector) to matrix to use R baseline package for data other than the sample data provided?

Tags: r, matrix, baseline

I have data in the form of a dataframe of x and y values that when plotted looks like this:

[image: basic plot]

(The portion highlighted in green corresponds to the dput() data below).

I want to use the baseline package to experiment with the different baseline correction algorithms described in "Liland, K. H., Almøy, T., & Mevik, B.-H. (2010). Optimal Choice of Baseline Correction for Multivariate Calibration of Spectra. Applied Spectroscopy, 64(9), 1007–1016. doi:10.1366/000370210792434350".

The package specifies that "data must be organized as row vectors in a matrix or data.frame", however, simply converting my y values to a matrix doesn't work:

```
> baseline(as.matrix(y, byrow=T))
Error in rep(3, p - 4) : invalid 'times' argument
```

The example data that is provided with the package has a structure that I can't interpret or figure out how to emulate with my own data.

```
> library(baseline)
> data(milk)
> str(milk)
'data.frame':   45 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ cow    : num  0 0.25 0.375 0.875 0.5 0.75 0.5 0.125 0 0.125 ...
 $ spectra: num [1:45, 1:21451] 1029 371 606 368 554 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : NULL
  .. ..$ : chr [1:21451] "4999.94078628963" "5001.55954267662" "5003.17856106153" "5004.79784144435" ...
 - attr(*, "terms")=Classes 'terms', 'formula'  language cow ~ spectra
  .. ..- attr(*, "variables")= language list(cow, spectra)
  .. ..- attr(*, "factors")= int [1:2, 1] 0 1
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "cow" "spectra"
  .. .. .. ..$ : chr "spectra"
  .. ..- attr(*, "term.labels")= chr "spectra"
  .. ..- attr(*, "order")= int 1
  .. ..- attr(*, "intercept")= int 1
  .. ..- attr(*, "response")= int 1
  .. ..- attr(*, ".Environment")=<environment: R_GlobalEnv> 
  .. ..- attr(*, "predvars")= language list(cow, spectra)
  .. ..- attr(*, "dataClasses")= Named chr [1:2] "numeric" "nmatrix.21451"
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "cow" "spectra"
```

If anyone can tell me how I can call baseline() on my own data, I would greatly appreciate it.

Here is a subsection of the data I'm working with, corresponding to the green highlighted portion of the plot above:

```
    > dput(fid_df[fid_df$rt>12.5&fid_df$rt<12.8,])
structure(list(rt = c(12.5002866914485, 12.5011200182712, 12.5019533450939, 
12.5027866719166, 12.5036199987393, 12.5044533255619, 12.5052866523846, 
12.5061199792073, 12.50695330603, 12.5077866328527, 12.5086199596754, 
12.5094532864981, 12.5102866133207, 12.5111199401434, 12.5119532669661, 
12.5127865937888, 12.5136199206115, 12.5144532474342, 12.5152865742568, 
12.5161199010795, 12.5169532279022, 12.5177865547249, 12.5186198815476, 
12.5194532083703, 12.5202865351929, 12.5211198620156, 12.5219531888383, 
12.522786515661, 12.5236198424837, 12.5244531693064, 12.5252864961291, 
12.5261198229517, 12.5269531497744, 12.5277864765971, 12.5286198034198, 
12.5294531302425, 12.5302864570652, 12.5311197838878, 12.5319531107105, 
12.5327864375332, 12.5336197643559, 12.5344530911786, 12.5352864180013, 
12.536119744824, 12.5369530716466, 12.5377863984693, 12.538619725292, 
12.5394530521147, 12.5402863789374, 12.5411197057601, 12.5419530325827, 
12.5427863594054, 12.5436196862281, 12.5444530130508, 12.5452863398735, 
12.5461196666962, 12.5469529935189, 12.5477863203415, 12.5486196471642, 
12.5494529739869, 12.5502863008096, 12.5511196276323, 12.551952954455, 
12.5527862812776, 12.5536196081003, 12.554452934923, 12.5552862617457, 
12.5561195885684, 12.5569529153911, 12.5577862422138, 12.5586195690364, 
12.5594528958591, 12.5602862226818, 12.5611195495045, 12.5619528763272, 
12.5627862031499, 12.5636195299725, 12.5644528567952, 12.5652861836179, 
12.5661195104406, 12.5669528372633, 12.567786164086, 12.5686194909087, 
12.5694528177313, 12.570286144554, 12.5711194713767, 12.5719527981994, 
12.5727861250221, 12.5736194518448, 12.5744527786674, 12.5752861054901, 
12.5761194323128, 12.5769527591355, 12.5777860859582, 12.5786194127809, 
12.5794527396035, 12.5802860664262, 12.5811193932489, 12.5819527200716, 
12.5827860468943, 12.583619373717, 12.5844527005397, 12.5852860273623, 
12.586119354185, 12.5869526810077, 12.5877860078304, 12.5886193346531, 
12.5894526614758, 12.5902859882984, 12.5911193151211, 12.5919526419438, 
12.5927859687665, 12.5936192955892, 12.5944526224119, 12.5952859492346, 
12.5961192760572, 12.5969526028799, 12.5977859297026, 12.5986192565253, 
12.599452583348, 12.6002859101707, 12.6011192369933, 12.601952563816, 
12.6027858906387, 12.6036192174614, 12.6044525442841, 12.6052858711068, 
12.6061191979295, 12.6069525247521, 12.6077858515748, 12.6086191783975, 
12.6094525052202, 12.6102858320429, 12.6111191588656, 12.6119524856882, 
12.6127858125109, 12.6136191393336, 12.6144524661563, 12.615285792979, 
12.6161191198017, 12.6169524466243, 12.617785773447, 12.6186191002697, 
12.6194524270924, 12.6202857539151, 12.6211190807378, 12.6219524075605, 
12.6227857343831, 12.6236190612058, 12.6244523880285, 12.6252857148512, 
12.6261190416739, 12.6269523684966, 12.6277856953192, 12.6286190221419, 
12.6294523489646, 12.6302856757873, 12.63111900261, 12.6319523294327, 
12.6327856562554, 12.633618983078, 12.6344523099007, 12.6352856367234, 
12.6361189635461, 12.6369522903688, 12.6377856171915, 12.6386189440141, 
12.6394522708368, 12.6402855976595, 12.6411189244822, 12.6419522513049, 
12.6427855781276, 12.6436189049503, 12.6444522317729, 12.6452855585956, 
12.6461188854183, 12.646952212241, 12.6477855390637, 12.6486188658864, 
12.649452192709, 12.6502855195317, 12.6511188463544, 12.6519521731771, 
12.6527854999998, 12.6536188268225, 12.6544521536452, 12.6552854804678, 
12.6561188072905, 12.6569521341132, 12.6577854609359, 12.6586187877586, 
12.6594521145813, 12.6602854414039, 12.6611187682266, 12.6619520950493, 
12.662785421872, 12.6636187486947, 12.6644520755174, 12.6652854023401, 
12.6661187291627, 12.6669520559854, 12.6677853828081, 12.6686187096308, 
12.6694520364535, 12.6702853632762, 12.6711186900988, 12.6719520169215, 
12.6727853437442, 12.6736186705669, 12.6744519973896, 12.6752853242123, 
12.6761186510349, 12.6769519778576, 12.6777853046803, 12.678618631503, 
12.6794519583257, 12.6802852851484, 12.6811186119711, 12.6819519387937, 
12.6827852656164, 12.6836185924391, 12.6844519192618, 12.6852852460845, 
12.6861185729072, 12.6869518997298, 12.6877852265525, 12.6886185533752, 
12.6894518801979, 12.6902852070206, 12.6911185338433, 12.691951860666, 
12.6927851874886, 12.6936185143113, 12.694451841134, 12.6952851679567, 
12.6961184947794, 12.6969518216021, 12.6977851484247, 12.6986184752474, 
12.6994518020701, 12.7002851288928, 12.7011184557155, 12.7019517825382, 
12.7027851093609, 12.7036184361835, 12.7044517630062, 12.7052850898289, 
12.7061184166516, 12.7069517434743, 12.707785070297, 12.7086183971196, 
12.7094517239423, 12.710285050765, 12.7111183775877, 12.7119517044104, 
12.7127850312331, 12.7136183580558, 12.7144516848784, 12.7152850117011, 
12.7161183385238, 12.7169516653465, 12.7177849921692, 12.7186183189919, 
12.7194516458145, 12.7202849726372, 12.7211182994599, 12.7219516262826, 
12.7227849531053, 12.723618279928, 12.7244516067506, 12.7252849335733, 
12.726118260396, 12.7269515872187, 12.7277849140414, 12.7286182408641, 
12.7294515676868, 12.7302848945094, 12.7311182213321, 12.7319515481548, 
12.7327848749775, 12.7336182018002, 12.7344515286229, 12.7352848554455, 
12.7361181822682, 12.7369515090909, 12.7377848359136, 12.7386181627363, 
12.739451489559, 12.7402848163817, 12.7411181432043, 12.741951470027, 
12.7427847968497, 12.7436181236724, 12.7444514504951, 12.7452847773178, 
12.7461181041404, 12.7469514309631, 12.7477847577858, 12.7486180846085, 
12.7494514114312, 12.7502847382539, 12.7511180650766, 12.7519513918992, 
12.7527847187219, 12.7536180455446, 12.7544513723673, 12.75528469919, 
12.7561180260127, 12.7569513528353, 12.757784679658, 12.7586180064807, 
12.7594513333034, 12.7602846601261, 12.7611179869488, 12.7619513137715, 
12.7627846405941, 12.7636179674168, 12.7644512942395, 12.7652846210622, 
12.7661179478849, 12.7669512747076, 12.7677846015302, 12.7686179283529, 
12.7694512551756, 12.7702845819983, 12.771117908821, 12.7719512356437, 
12.7727845624663, 12.773617889289, 12.7744512161117, 12.7752845429344, 
12.7761178697571, 12.7769511965798, 12.7777845234025, 12.7786178502251, 
12.7794511770478, 12.7802845038705, 12.7811178306932, 12.7819511575159, 
12.7827844843386, 12.7836178111612, 12.7844511379839, 12.7852844648066, 
12.7861177916293, 12.786951118452, 12.7877844452747, 12.7886177720974, 
12.78945109892, 12.7902844257427, 12.7911177525654, 12.7919510793881, 
12.7927844062108, 12.7936177330335, 12.7944510598561, 12.7952843866788, 
12.7961177135015, 12.7969510403242, 12.7977843671469, 12.7986176939696, 
12.7994510207923), value = c(17.3893229166667, 17.394140625, 
17.3994791666667, 17.3966145833333, 17.397265625, 17.4009114583333, 
17.4036458333333, 17.400390625, 17.3940104166667, 17.3908854166667, 
17.3873697916667, 17.3858072916667, 17.3841145833333, 17.3834635416667, 
17.383984375, 17.3837239583333, 17.3838541666667, 17.3850260416667, 
17.3904947916667, 17.3954427083333, 17.39375, 17.3897135416667, 
17.387109375, 17.3890625, 17.3876302083333, 17.385546875, 17.3850260416667, 
17.390234375, 17.39921875, 17.4076822916667, 17.4131510416667, 
17.41484375, 17.4111979166667, 17.402734375, 17.3953125, 17.3915364583333, 
17.3934895833333, 17.3923177083333, 17.3938802083333, 17.3967447916667, 
17.398828125, 17.4, 17.396484375, 17.4, 17.39921875, 17.4032552083333, 
17.4138020833333, 17.4260416666667, 17.4364583333333, 17.4458333333333, 
17.4639322916667, 17.491015625, 17.5239583333333, 17.5647135416667, 
17.6229166666667, 17.6997395833333, 17.7994791666667, 17.916015625, 
18.0544270833333, 18.2184895833333, 18.4170572916667, 18.6494791666667, 
18.914453125, 19.2151041666667, 19.5665364583333, 19.9688802083333, 
20.4143229166667, 20.8876302083333, 21.3850260416667, 21.9104166666667, 
22.4467447916667, 23.0069010416667, 23.5716145833333, 24.1360677083333, 
24.6528645833333, 25.1217447916667, 25.5454427083333, 25.9471354166667, 
26.2817708333333, 26.5583333333333, 26.7454427083333, 26.8537760416667, 
26.9045572916667, 26.889453125, 26.82734375, 26.6755208333333, 
26.442578125, 26.1438802083333, 25.7912760416667, 25.437109375, 
25.0861979166667, 24.7126302083333, 24.262890625, 23.73359375, 
23.1990885416667, 22.7178385416667, 22.28359375, 21.8391927083333, 
21.3856770833333, 20.9497395833333, 20.56640625, 20.2286458333333, 
19.9221354166667, 19.6524739583333, 19.3998697916667, 19.1759114583333, 
18.9670572916667, 18.7893229166667, 18.640625, 18.5109375, 18.401171875, 
18.3026041666667, 18.2216145833333, 18.1454427083333, 18.0764322916667, 
18.0162760416667, 17.9623697916667, 17.9102864583333, 17.8688802083333, 
17.8309895833333, 17.8029947916667, 17.7690104166667, 17.7415364583333, 
17.7149739583333, 17.693359375, 17.6713541666667, 17.6526041666667, 
17.631640625, 17.6157552083333, 17.6013020833333, 17.5877604166667, 
17.5740885416667, 17.5670572916667, 17.55703125, 17.545703125, 
17.5307291666667, 17.527734375, 17.5272135416667, 17.5216145833333, 
17.5140625, 17.5040364583333, 17.4944010416667, 17.4796875, 17.469921875, 
17.4647135416667, 17.4657552083333, 17.46640625, 17.4638020833333, 
17.4580729166667, 17.4485677083333, 17.4446614583333, 17.4430989583333, 
17.4475260416667, 17.4428385416667, 17.4401041666667, 17.433984375, 
17.4352864583333, 17.4342447916667, 17.4309895833333, 17.42890625, 
17.4265625, 17.4248697916667, 17.42109375, 17.4109375, 17.4052083333333, 
17.403125, 17.4092447916667, 17.413671875, 17.4153645833333, 
17.4123697916667, 17.4123697916667, 17.4091145833333, 17.4052083333333, 
17.401953125, 17.4052083333333, 17.40703125, 17.410546875, 17.4084635416667, 
17.4096354166667, 17.4084635416667, 17.4135416666667, 17.4209635416667, 
17.42265625, 17.42265625, 17.4223958333333, 17.4248697916667, 
17.418359375, 17.4127604166667, 17.4125, 17.4184895833333, 17.4180989583333, 
17.4111979166667, 17.4076822916667, 17.4158854166667, 17.425390625, 
17.4279947916667, 17.424609375, 17.4229166666667, 17.4147135416667, 
17.40625, 17.4014322916667, 17.4071614583333, 17.4125, 17.416796875, 
17.415234375, 17.4084635416667, 17.402734375, 17.4018229166667, 
17.4032552083333, 17.4009114583333, 17.40078125, 17.40078125, 
17.4015625, 17.4002604166667, 17.4006510416667, 17.4001302083333, 
17.398046875, 17.399609375, 17.4014322916667, 17.4, 17.39765625, 
17.394140625, 17.3958333333333, 17.3985677083333, 17.399609375, 
17.3979166666667, 17.3924479166667, 17.3860677083333, 17.3852864583333, 
17.3834635416667, 17.3805989583333, 17.3751302083333, 17.3782552083333, 
17.3834635416667, 17.3848958333333, 17.3802083333333, 17.3809895833333, 
17.3842447916667, 17.3846354166667, 17.3779947916667, 17.3703125, 
17.372265625, 17.3786458333333, 17.3860677083333, 17.38203125, 
17.3813802083333, 17.38203125, 17.3881510416667, 17.38984375, 
17.394921875, 17.3963541666667, 17.3998697916667, 17.3963541666667, 
17.3932291666667, 17.3854166666667, 17.3725260416667, 17.3647135416667, 
17.36328125, 17.372265625, 17.3756510416667, 17.380078125, 17.3766927083333, 
17.378515625, 17.37578125, 17.382421875, 17.38359375, 17.379296875, 
17.3759114583333, 17.37578125, 17.3803385416667, 17.378515625, 
17.3837239583333, 17.3829427083333, 17.38359375, 17.3768229166667, 
17.3790364583333, 17.380078125, 17.3846354166667, 17.3837239583333, 
17.3869791666667, 17.3813802083333, 17.3889322916667, 17.388671875, 
17.39375, 17.3911458333333, 17.3891927083333, 17.3889322916667, 
17.386328125, 17.3830729166667, 17.3783854166667, 17.3748697916667, 
17.3796875, 17.3830729166667, 17.383203125, 17.3755208333333, 
17.37421875, 17.371875, 17.3735677083333, 17.37109375, 17.373046875, 
17.3774739583333, 17.3782552083333, 17.3748697916667, 17.3764322916667, 
17.3807291666667, 17.3876302083333, 17.3846354166667, 17.3802083333333, 
17.376171875, 17.3727864583333, 17.3735677083333, 17.3796875, 
17.3864583333333, 17.3876302083333, 17.3845052083333, 17.3850260416667, 
17.3880208333333, 17.3891927083333, 17.3880208333333, 17.3830729166667, 
17.3782552083333, 17.3765625, 17.379296875, 17.3829427083333, 
17.3869791666667, 17.3881510416667, 17.384765625, 17.3763020833333, 
17.376953125, 17.3786458333333, 17.3817708333333, 17.3821614583333, 
17.3859375, 17.3876302083333, 17.3837239583333, 17.381640625, 
17.37890625, 17.3802083333333, 17.3825520833333, 17.3881510416667, 
17.3888020833333, 17.3864583333333, 17.3825520833333, 17.3834635416667, 
17.386328125, 17.3854166666667, 17.384375, 17.3852864583333, 
17.390234375, 17.3916666666667, 17.38828125, 17.3891927083333, 
17.3901041666667, 17.3950520833333, 17.3963541666667, 17.3970052083333, 
17.3907552083333, 17.3846354166667, 17.3760416666667, 17.3743489583333
)), row.names = 15002:15361, class = "data.frame")
```

(p.s the question here: [R-package(baseline) application to sample dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37346967/r-packagebaseline-application-to-sample-dataset) seems to have a similar problem, but doesn't address how to turn simple x,y data into the format required by the baseline package).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The baseline package expects spectra to appear in rows, but your code creates a matrix with the spectrum in a single column. If you change the conversion from data.frame to matrix to the following it should work:

```
baseline(matrix(y, nrow=1))
```

The problem was caused by two things, using `as.matrix()`, which does not take the arguments you need, and using `byrow=T` instead of `nrow=1`. `byrow` controls the direction in which the matrix is filled, either by rows or by columns, but has no effect on the output dimensions.

The extra fuzz in the `milk` data is not helping here, so I will remove it in the next package update. I will also look into the possibility of allowing single spectra to be handled in vector format instead of explicitly forcing matrix input.

P.S. I was able to copy out your data with a tiny extra effort, but suspect that you need the raw data to directly copy-paste from this page as the `dput` line contains som subsetting.

Comment: Thanks Kristian, I'm glad it was as simple as that.  I got pretty lost down a rabbit hole of trying to understand what S4 objects are thinking that had something to do with my problem.  Now I can proceed with fitting various baselines to my data.